# installing open cv for the Dev C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to install open cv library and i am using Dev c++ compiler. I tried several times to install open cv, but it doesnt work properly. i have read some documents which says, it is necessary to intall cmake first. but, i tried without it. can anyone guide me to install open cv please (please give me procedure, step by step).

Comment: @Pandya >> downloaded and installed opencv 2.2 then confugured the opencv with dev c++. here i followd the following way (in dev c++ tools->compiler options window, then set a new compiler as opencv, also set the binaries of the directory as c:\opencv2.2\bin and set the libraries as c:\opencv2.2\lib. then set C-inlcueds as c:\opencv2.2\include and set C++ inlude as c:\opencv2.2\include. i.e. i followed the instructiongiven in this url; http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/DevCpp

Comment: Good job. I still disagree with using something that's completely outdated that you can easily move away from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote [a procedure](http://groups.google.com/group/ccckc/browse_thread/thread/d3b4344c7e06fef9/c106e6b151b7afcd) for [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) on Win32 a little while back.

Comment: >>
sorry., i undestood wrongly. this is for the code-block. but, i need for dev c++. help me again

Answer (score 4):

I would answer this properly, but, here is my very important recommendation.

## Don't use Dev-C++!

It isn't really maintained (last release was in 2005), it is mostly meant for beginning programmers (I learned from it myself), its a pain to do anything it was not meant to do.

I would suggest [Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/), [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/), or [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/). If you have a computer that's pretty new, then, [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/).

If you are willing to use these technologies, a lot of people will gladly give you answers.

Comment: no way to go back. i already use dev for writing codes. so i have to continue with dev c++.

Comment: Its not like that. You can move very easily. Just either copy and paste your code into new files, or, just make your new IDE import a project from dev-C++

Comment: Also, just being picky, it's not writing codes, it's writing code.